# sending outlook 2010 email using PHP

Tags: php, outlook

Have already added:

[COM_DOT_NET]

extension=php_com_dotnet.dll

at the end of php.inI file

This is the code I'm using:

```
    if (!defined("olMailItem")) define("olMailItem",0); 

    $objApp = new COM ( "Outlook.Application" ) or die ( "Cannot Load Outlook.Application" );
    $namespace = $objApp->GetNamespace("MAPI");  // or MAPI.Session
    $namespace->Logon();

    $myItem = $objApp->CreateItem (olMailItem);
    $myItem->To = $email;
    $myItem->SentOnBehalfOfName = "IT.Helpdesk@mycompany.com";
    $myItem->Subject = "Notification: application form submitted successfully.";
    $myItem->Body ="Hi " . $realname .",
    You have successfully submitted the applicant form for (".$firstname." , ".$lastname.")
The application has been sent to the respective managers for approval.


    Thank you,
    Applicant Portal";  
    $myItem->Send ();
```

The full error msg:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `Outlook.Application': Access is denied. ' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\doForm.php:268 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\doForm.php(268): com->com('Outlook.Applica...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\doForm.php on line 268

Answer (score 0):

Automating Outlook from PHP is not a good idea. The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article states the following:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

As you may see, that way of automating Outlook is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a workaround for two straight days. My application was working perfectly and suddenly I stumbled upon the same exception.

The problem was that Outlook and my Apache server were running under different rights (one as a user, the other as an admin). I ran both as a user and everything went back to normal.

Comment: Do not use Outlook in a service. Just don't. It is guaranteed to fail sooner or later.